# iPhone Delegates And Making 2 Instantiated Objects Talk To One Another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have had about 6 hours trying to work out custom application delegates. even following tutorials i end up with errors!

I need a simple way of allowing one object to talk to another.

I have a root view. then another view which then pushes onto the stack with a list of options. then another view showing the relevant options based on the previous selection.

So basically 3 views, and i need view 3 to pass data back to view 1 when i popBackToRootViewController.... This is becoming a huge headache, for something that in theory should be so simple. I have previously just thrown data into nsuserdefaults but using protocols in the way apple suggest to do it.

Please can someone help me understand :)

Answer (score 1):

There a different ways to solve that problem. First of all, you could pass the first View over and over to the View you are making changes on and then call a method of view 1. I won't recommend that.
Another, much easier way is to use [Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Just register your first View in the notification center `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(somethingChanged) name:@"aStringWichIsUniqeForCallingSomethingChanged" object:nil];`. You have to provide and implement a callback method (somethingChanged in my case). In your subwiew where the things happen, you have to post a notification by doing `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"aStringWichIsUniqeForCallingSomethingChanged" object:nil];`. And don't forget to remove the view from the notificationcenter if they are not needed anymore! 
    `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];`
A third possibility is to use a singelton (like the app delegate) which contains all views that should communicate. Simple make all views as ivars & properties for them in this singleton and implement in each of them methods which should be called if something changes. Then call `[[singelton sharedInstance] view1] somethingChanged]`.

If i say View, i mean viewController, but i'm to lazy to write that. ;)
Hope, that helps!

Answer (score 0):

*Protocols* and *delegation* formalize a concept which works even if you don't follow the formal rules: It's about declaring a way for objects to talk to each other about the same thing, especially in those cases where you either don't have or don't want control about one of the objects, or in cases where things get complex and you want everything nice and tidy so it's easier to reuse the code.

In those cases however where a rather small, well known set of information is to be passed back and forth between two (or more) well known objects which are unlikely to be reused, informality is quite ok.

This means you could:

- provide the *sending* object with a property of the type of the *receiving* object
- implement a method in the *receiving* object which will take the information to be sent as an argument
- at some point, for example in your case when the root controller pushes the child which becomes the *sending* object, the *receiving* object will set itself as the value of the *sending* object
- if the *sending* object has information to send, it uses the reference to the *receiving* object to send it a message calling the earlier mentioned method, passing the information as an argument

As I mentioned before, this makes sense for glue code. You shouldn't be doing it this way though, if:

- you're working in a team and you're working on one object and a teammate is working on the other
- it's obvious you may be able to use the same functionality in a future project. In this case, think about having an intermediate subclass between your original superclass and your app-specific subclass, one that encapsulates the core functionality and offers a formal protocol to interface with it
- the exchange of information involves objects of different classes within the same app
- the exchange of information itself is rather complex and one (or two) glue methods wouldn't cover it

Comment: thanks for this, but i am banging my head against a brick wall... all i need to know is where you declare the protocol in the class recieving or sending the data? and how to set the classes delegate to anything other than self.

Comment: That depends - protocols allow data flow in both directions. Either objects of the class offering the protocol send out information by calling the delegate, but this can be used for polling as well. I'd put the protocol into the class for which encapsulation makes more sense. The same class that implements the protocol also needs a property for the delegate. It's then up to you how to set the delegate - if you make it an outlet, you can assign it in Interface Builder too. Otherwise you need to set it programmatically at any point prior to exchange of information.